# What would I call the things inside a document in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I havent really ran into a error, but I was wondering. MongoDB calls each thing inside a collection a "document" I was wondering what you call the things inside a document.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're referring to, but if you look at the MongoDB docs, they describe all the details of individual Documents.

Comment: yeah sorry.. I had a really hard time with explaining it, but what you do call the things inside a document? 
And thanks ill take a look at the MongoDB docs

Comment: Yes!! I found the answer to my question, ill post the answer right now.

Comment: See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit i just posted an answer yesterday, im waiting for 13 more hours until I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after looking for a long time. This is what you call the things inside a document. Its called a field.

```json
#this entire thing is called a document. 

#The fields in this document are: name, age, status, and groups. 
#The values in this document are: "sue", 26, "A", and ["news", "sports"]

Hope this helps anyone who had the same question as me!

{
    name: "sue", 
    age: 26,
    status "A",
    groups: ["news", "sports"]       

}
```

Comment: Just note: If you're going to post things like code, json, etc, please use formatted text, not images of text (and what you posted looks like a direct screengrab from the docs). Please see [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) which lists many reasons why this is important.

Comment: Fixed it! Any more suggestions?